# Mongoose and bulk update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First time working with MongoDB and Mongoose.

I have written an edit function which do something with the input params and then call an update on the model:

```
edit: function (input) {
    var query = ...
    var document = ...
    return Model.update(query, document, {multi: true});
}
```

The function return a Promise with the number of affected documents.

I know that the Mongoose update function

> updates documents in the database without returning them

so I was wondering if there is a way to somehow:

1. run my edit function
2. if everything goes well, run a find on the model in order to retrieve the updated documents, and return the find's Promise.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the `multi`? Because if you use `findOneAndUpdate` method you can retrieve the updated documented directly from the callback (using `new` option) http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Yes I need the `multi`: it's a bulk update which I use to update more than one document at time. I would like the retrieve all the updated documents (not only the number of). In other words: I would need an hypothetical `findAllAndUpdate` with the `new` option :D